# Exploratory Development vs Incremental Development

Tags: software, engineering

In Software Engineering Methodologies... The Evolutionary Development contains Exploratory & Prototyping...
Is Exploratory Development same as Incremental Development... What do you mean by exploratory Development?

The terms are taken from 
[Software Engineering - Ian Sommerville](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137035152)

Comment: @DocBrown Just edited!

Comment: Use comments to respond to other users.  @reply does not work in posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exploratory Development == experimental. New to the world or new to you or your company. means trying something and then maybe having the guts to leave it and go some other way.

Incremental means doing in stages. So you can develop something similiar to what has been done before, but a smaller feature set at a time, test and ship quickly & often, with more involved QA & dev ops. Be agile and have more releases and hopefully happier customers.

Comment: Most important: Exploratory = experimental = be prepared to throw it away. Sometimes some team members prefer A, some prefer B, but some claim B doesn't work. The  exploratory development to try B may very well be worth the money if it fals, because it shuts up those who are against A.

Answer (score 1):

Exploratory development, to me, means trying out new development technologies or infrastructure solutions.

It could also mean building new functionality from scratch, or as part of an existing system. Maybe you've been asked to look at how something might work, before getting official go ahead for a bigger piece of work.

Incremental development is about progressively working your way through the development life cycle, usually meaning short development time periods, releasing more often etc.